How to get value of python series list?
This is one column of my pandas dataframe. I just want to get the value for Type__c which is Transfer.
{'attributes': {'type': 'CaseStep__c', 'url': '/abc/data/v59.0/sobjects/CaseStep__c/xyz'}, 'Type__c': 'Transfer'}
I tried to get the value with these expression
df_rtl_py_raw["PreviousStep"].Type__c
But I think something like this is not possible. Do I have to trim this whole column value?

df_rtl_py_raw["PreviousStep"].str.get('Type__c')
